# PowerBI Maps not supported SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, powerbi

I have built a PowerBi report using ArcGIS based on a SP list that stores user information i.e where they are based when they submit a request.

However when using the PowerBI webpart on the modern pages I get this message.

"for embed visuals arcgis maps for power bi is not currently supported"

Is there a way around this? As the requirement is to view the map on the SPO page

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the ArcGIS maps are not yet supported with Publish to Web. It is by design.

There is a similar post:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/ArcGIS-maps-in-embed-code-not-working/td-p/152323

More reference:

[ArcGIS maps in Power BI service and Power BI Desktop by Esri.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-visualization-arcgis)